# Change underline color and floating hint color of TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-styles, android-textinputlayout

I'm using the above property in my `TextInputLayout` theme to make the underline color of the `TextInputLayout` green when activated.

```
      <item name="colorControlActivated">#27e905</item>
```

Its works fine and I get the following result

[image]

But as you can see `colorControlActivated` also affects the floating hint color. I need a different color for floating hint. Is there any way t do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add these styles in styles.xml

```
  <style name="textInputLayout.GrayLabel"
    parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/AppTheme.TextFloatLabelAppearance</item>
   </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.TextFloatLabelAppearance"         
     parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <!-- Floating label appearance here -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/YOUR_TEXT_SIZE</item>
</style>
```

and use it like this:-

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/textInputLayout.GrayLabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8dp">
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update 2021**

You can use this attribute to control the underline color

```
app:boxStrokeColor="@color/green"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want change hint color of TextInputLayout just create this style:

```
       <style name="style">
            <item name="colorAccent">your_color</item>
       </style>
```

and then

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    ...
        app:theme="@style/style" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use these styles in your style.xml

```
<style name="myHintText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
    </style>
```

**NOTE** requires min api level 21

Answer (score 0):

For unfocused bottom line color, use `<color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color" tools:override="true">#673AB7</color>`
in your colors.xml or style.xml file

You also need to put `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in your parent root tag.